# What is the difference between these Backbone/Underscore .bind() methods?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
window.SomeView = Backbone.View.extrend({
    initialize1: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    initialize2: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
    },

    initialize3: function() {
        _.bind(this.render, this);
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },
});
```

With help from some SO members, I was able to get my test project working with binding methods initialize1 and initialize2; what I don't understand is why initialize3 doesn't work?

**documentation:** [_.bind(function, object, [*arguments])](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

Comment: there is a minor typo 'extrend' should be 'extend'.  i cant just make that one change because edits require that at least 4-5 characters be changed.  i dont want to do other random changes just to push the edit through.  i am O-C about this sort of thing :).  Could you please make the edit?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are three main differences; [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) only works on one method at a time, allows currying, and **returns** the bound function (this also means that you can use `_.bind` on an anonymous function):

> Bind a **function** to an **object**, meaning that whenever the function is called, the value of *this* will be the **object**. Optionally, bind **arguments** to the **function** to pre-fill them, also known as **currying**.

whereas [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) binds many **named** methods at once, doesn't allow currying, and binds the them in-place:

> Binds a number of methods on the **object**, specified by **methodNames**, to be run in the context of that object whenever they are invoked.

So these two chunks of code are roughly equivalent:

```
// Bind methods (not names) one a time.
o.m1 = _.bind(o.m1, o);
o.m2 = _.bind(o.m2, o);

// Bind several named methods at once.
_.bindAll(o, 'm1', 'm2');
```

But there is no `bindAll` equivalent to this:

```
f = _.bind(o, o.m1, 'pancakes');
```

That makes `f()` the same as `o.m1('pancakes')` (this is [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)).

---

So, when you say this:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'render');
this.model.bind('change', this.render);
```

You're binding the method `render` to have a `this` that matches the current `this` and then you're binding `this.render` to the change event on `this.model`.

When you say this:

```
this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
```

You're doing the same thing. And this:

```
_.bind(this.render, this);
this.model.bind('change', this.render);
```

doesn't work because you're throwing away the return value of `_.bind` (i.e. you throw away the bound function).

Comment: Ah. That clarifies a lot.  Is it safe to say that _.bindAll modifies the actual method of the of the model, affecting every subsequent call to it; while _.bind leaves the original method in tact, but returns a modified (bound) version for use?

Comment: @rkw: Right, `_.bind` returns the bound function (or probably wraps the function and returns the bound wrapper) and (AFAIK) leaves the original alone.

Comment: oops, my mistake.  Your verbage was just very similar to the discussion of bind right above this anchor in addy osmani's book http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#collections