# Backbone _.bind not working

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

In my view class initialize function, `_.bind(this.appendSection, this)` does not work, but `_.bindAll(this, 'appendSection')` works. I am very confused...

Here is the code:

```
TemplateBuilder.Views.TemplateView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('div#evalTemplate'),

        initialize: function(){
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
            //_.bind(this.appendSection, this);
            _.bindAll(this, 'appendSection');                
        },

        events: {
            'click button#addSection': 'addSection'
        },

        render: function(){
            this.collection.each(this.appendSection);
            return this;
        },

        appendSection: function(section){                
            var view = new TemplateBuilder.Views.InstructionView({model: section});
            this.$el.append(view.render().el);
        },

        addSection: function(){
            var newSection = new TemplateBuilder.Models.Section();                
            this.collection.add(newSection);
            this.appendSection(newSection);
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#bind):

> **bind** `_.bind(function, object, [*arguments])`
>
> Bind a function to an object, meaning that whenever the function is called, the value of *this* will be the **object**. [...]
>
> ```
> var func = function(greeting){ return greeting + ': ' + this.name };
> func = _.bind(func, {name : 'moe'}, 'hi');
> func();
> => 'hi: moe'
> ```

Unfortunately the manual isn't quite so fine and you have to see what's implied by the example code:

```
func = _.bind(func, ...);
```

`_.bind` returns the bound function, it doesn't modify it in-place. You'd have to say this:

```
this.appendSection = _.bind(this.appendSection, this);
```

if you wanted to use `_.bind`. [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) on the other hand, binds methods in place. There is more discussion on these methods [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7087753/479863).

Comment: Damn, I know this long time ago, now I remembered everything... Thanks!