# Backbone View, Event Handler and bindAll

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I have something like this

```
$ ->
  class MyView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
      stuff

    $("body").on "click", ".stuff", ->
      @functionB()

    functionA: (new_date) ->
      stuff

    functionB: () =>
      stuff

  new MyView(el: $mySelector)
```

I want to call functionB from the event handler.
I know that I can use fat arrows, but how would I do it with _.bindAll

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm guessing that `$("body").on "click", ".stuff", ->` is actually inside your `initialize` method and you just have a formatting problem. Your code doesn't make a lot of sense otherwise.

The problem you'll run into is that jQuery controls what `@` (AKA `this`) is inside the callback function. So just binding `functionB` won't be sufficient because you can't get at `functionB` without having the right `@` already.

In your specific case, none of this really matters because `functionB` is defined as a bound function (using `=>`) and you have no need for an anonymous wrapper in the event handler, just hand `on` the function itself:

```
$("body").on "click", ".stuff", @functionB
```

If for some reason you insist on bind an anonymous function then you'd want to use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) (or [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) rather than [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll); `_.bindAll` binds functions (by name) to a specific `@` but you want to find a specific function (which has no name) to a specific `@`, see [**What is the difference between these Backbone/Underscore .bind() methods?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7087564/479863) for more discussion on the difference. You'd say something like:

```
$("body").on "click", ".stuff", _(-> @functionB()).bind(@)

# or

unbound_function = -> @functionB()
$("body").on "click", ".stuff", _.bind unbound_function, @
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using backbone, you can either use the native syntax for binding, `=>` or the built in underscore methods of `_bind` and `_bindAll`. they do the same thing, its just a matter of where you declare them. If you bind them at function declaration, you can then have a reference to them if you want to dispose of the event listener.

```
$ ->
  class MyView extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ->
      stuff

    $("body").on "click", ".stuff", @functionB
    # alternatively, inline as an anonymous function (then you can 
    # leave the declaration of functionB below as `->` )
    $("body").on "click", ".stuff", => @functionB(arguments...)

    functionA: (new_date) ->
      stuff

    functionB: () =>
      stuff
```